# Refresh PyDev import paths in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, import, path, pydev

I'm using Eclipse Helios under Ubuntu.

Whenever I install a new library under `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/` using `pip`, Eclipse doesn't see it and complains about invalid imports. I double checked the library is in place. Importing it works from the interpreter. Refreshing the PyDev configuration or restarting the IDE doesn't work. Note: the mentioned path is on the list of library paths in the Python interpreter tab.

Does anybody know of a remedy to this, and if not how to track down the actual cause.

Comment: @vartec Definitely not. I told you - I restarted the IDE, deleted and added the Python interpreter. So no, it's not that easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I installed the library from an egg. Egg folders need to be added manually or otherwise PyDev won't see them. Another thing that confused me a little was that I had another version of the same library installed as a regular folder. That folder however didn't have `__init__.py` in it.